# Why can't I install python3.6-dev on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.6, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3.6-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6-dev'
```

Why am I getting this error and what is the correct way to install the package?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The package is not available in 16.04. But if you need it in 16.04 you can add the deadsnakes package repository:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa \
&& sudo apt update \
&& sudo apt install python3.6
```

Comment: 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa' solved my "Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.9-dev'" on Ubuntu 22.04 TLS

Comment: [Answers shouldn't contain "Edit:"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011). There is a ***full edit history*** here. If the old answer is no longer valid or valuable it should be removed. Alternatively, different sections can be qualified with, for example, *"For Ubuntu versions prior to X"* and *"For Ubuntu version Y and later"*. The answer should be as if it was written today (how it came to be that isn't of any concern to (most) readers).

Answer (score 29):

This ppa worked like a charm on ubuntu 16.04. Posting here for others.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Comment: perfectly worked for me to make 3.6 default python  in ubuntu 16..04 LTS                                            
  update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10

Answer (score 10):

For those who tried to install Python 3.6 and got same error as that one above, this can help you as well as us. It helped me fix out the problem.

1. Open a terminal and then run this command to add the [PPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#Package_Archives):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
   ```
2. Then check updates and install Python 3.6 via commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python3.6
   ```

Now to make sure you had install successfully, just run `python3.6-v` or `python3.6`

For more details, check at "[How to Install Python 3.6.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/)".

Note: Linux 16.04 uses Python v 2.7 as the default one. If you need to use Python 3.6 in your project, just set *python-3.6* as the default version for this project. It's better than
using the `sudo update-alternatives ...` command, and then your terminal will vanish :(.

Comment: Jonathan Repo has problems. After install from here, I faced a lot of problems in getting pip work for me. Go for deadsnakes repo instead. 

Kenneth of requests library says the same: https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/linux/

Comment: The pb u may face once u try to use sudo update-alternatives this has made my terminal vanish other ways it's ok i think do not u think so ? But since u think it may lead to many issues that we can avoid so it's better to use another solution, thank you :).

Answer (score 8):

The package is too new. It's not available in the older 16.04 release. It's available in the newer [Ubuntu 16.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3.6&searchon=names).

Comment: Why you do this ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

This `ppa:jonathonf` did not work for me.

```
 ppa:deadsnakes
```

is working fine for now.

What worked was:

1. Open a terminal
2. Execute the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install python3.6
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

I guess they changed the name of repository.