# Why can't I install python3.8-dev on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.8

This comes as a wider issue of [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) with [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) 2.4 throwing a hissy fit over which version of Python they want to use, but I can't follow any of the guidance I've found to fix it, because I need *python3.8-dev* and it doesn't want to install:

```
apt install python3.8-dev
...
E: Unable to locate package python3.8-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.8-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.8-dev'
```

I have already done:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt install software-properties-common
apt update
apt upgrade
```

which all succeed. However, none have so far led to success with installing *python3.8-dev*.

The output of `lsb_release -a` is [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus):

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

I feel like I'm going mad. Everything worked fine and today it just didn't.
I do of course already have Python 3.8 installed.

Comment: This question belongs on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621584/why-cant-i-install-python3-6-dev-on-ubuntu16-04) very similar question on here I assumed it was fine

Comment: Installing tools needed for software development is ... borderline on-topic for StackOverflow.  But I agree it would be *better* to ask it on AskUbuntu, because it is very Ubuntu specific.

Comment: Considering I literally said I followed those same instructions to no avail, erm, no, I do need to ask this question, otherwise I wouldn't be here. Assuming I can't migrate my own question I'll copy-paste it over there.

Comment: Well ... the answer for that question is the same as for your question.  So you probably didn't need to ask this one anyway.  (Just install `python3.8-dev` from "deadsnakes" instead of `python3.6-dev`)   In the unlikely (!!) event that whose instructions don't work, you should add details of what you actually did to your question ... so that someone can help you figure it out.

Comment: And if you are going to re-ask on AskUbuntu, delete this question so that people don't waste their time on it.  (Ordinary users don't have the option of migrating questions.  It is a diamond moderator action.)

Comment: (And finally .... isn't it time you upgraded to a more recent Ubuntu?  16.04 is now in the ESM phase, which means that you need to pay for Canonical Advantage to get security patches.)

Comment: "several times without success." - It would be helpful if you described what actually happened ...

Comment: `unlikely (!!)` well it didn't work. Like I said in the question already I used the deadsnakes ppa but have now made this more explicit. `several times without success.` literally the same error. Python3.8-dev not found.

Comment: Did you try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/nightly` ?   According to https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/nightly/+packages, the `python3.8-dev` package is being built

Comment: [deadsnakes doesn't support 16.04](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). It supports 18.04 and 20.04

Comment: Ah bloody hell. So my only option is upgrading Ubuntu? Is it likely to break anything if I upgrade? It's odd because it used to work. Found this gist discussion where deadsnakes removed support at some point which broke someone's script: https://gist.github.com/ptantiku/aca8d955296d5dee01bd9ed1c3027d8c

I guess I could compile python from source but that deadsnakes page mentions something about compatibility that I'm not savvy enough to understand.

Comment: I think what I'll do tomorrow if there's no new answers here is ask another question to see if anyone has insight as to why Apache is being awful and if the only conclusion is needing py-dev then I'll upgrade Ubuntu and add that process as a self-answer here. Thanks for the research both :)

Answer (score 3):

*ppa:deadsnakes* was decommissioned for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus).
Try to build a custom .deb package.

Comment: I figured this out eventually. Just a bit of a shame the old versions weren't left public as there *was* a working 3.8 version for Xenial for a time, I think.

Comment: Hi @Aleks is there a .deb package that has the same effect as "sudo apt-get install python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-distutils python3.8-venv " ? i.e. it includes the dev, disutils and venv packages ?

Comment: In my case it was built according to official release source from python. You can adjust sources and modules during your build development @fatbringer

Comment: hi -- deadsnakes here -- I have limited space on the PPA, and I can't update packages after ubuntu has marked them end-of-life.  so unfortunately I delete them so I can support newer python versions and newer OS releases (and eliminate the "can I have the latest patch version for (eol'd version) kthx" drive by issues)

Comment: @anthonysottile Oh hey, the snake itself! That's unfortunate, though it has eventually prompted to me to just torch my old server and start over. I guess it stops people whining (except me apparently!) If you post this as an answer I can mark it as such and put this question to bed :)

Comment: @ch4rl1e97
"I figured this out eventually."  What was your solution?

Comment: @TommyGibbons By "figured this out" I mean I figured out that the deadsnakes ppa was decommissioned for end-of-life Ubuntu versions, not that I figured a solution. The solution really was to just update Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like deadsnakes repo no longer offers python3.8. This is what I see when I try to add the repo in Ubuntu 16.04

## Supported Ubuntu and Python Versions

- Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) Python3.5 - Python3.7, Python3.9 - Python3.11
- Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) Python3.7 - Python3.9, Python3.11
- Note: Python2.7 (all), Python 3.8 (focal), Python 3.10 (jammy) are not provided by deadsnakes as upstream ubuntu provides those packages.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way right now is to use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). Here's a good guide:

*[How to Install Pyenv on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pyenv-on-ubuntu-18-04/)*

If the 'pyenv global' command doesn't change the default version, run the following:

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

Comment: ah but we cant make the python 3.8 venv without having installed the package. right now we cant even install the package !

Comment: PYENV, not venv :). Pyenv is a version manager that allows you to install a desired version.

Comment: What is pyenv supposed achieve or allow? Why pyenv? What is the theory of operation? Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71797161/edit) a bit (it doesn't have to be along)? (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)